# Move vertical list of sections-subsections down

Tags: beamer

I'd like to move the vertical "index" of section and subsection that appears in themes like "Goettingen" down. I tried to add a vertical skip with `addtobeamertemplate`, but that moves all the sidebar content down, while what I want is to move just the "index", not Author/Title, so to gain free vertical space between "author" and "section 1". I'm attaching some example code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Goettingen}

\title[Title]{title}
\author[Author]{author}

\addtobeamertemplate{sidebar right}{\vskip25pt}{}
\begin{document}
\section{Section 1}
\subsection{1}
\frame{1}
\subsection{2}
\frame{2}
\subsection{3}
\frame{3}
\subsection{4} 
\frame{4}
\subsection{5} 
\frame{5}
\subsection{6} 
\frame{6} 
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove your `\addtobeamertemplate` and add

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd\insertverticalnavigation{\dohead}{\vskip25pt\dohead}{}{}
```

to your preamble.

This searches for the definition of `\insertverticalnavigation` into beamer sources and adds a a vertical skip just before the vertical navigator is printed by the `\dohead` command.

[image: before] [image: after]